# Convergence of $f_n = \sin(x+\frac{1}{n})$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, uniform-convergence

Is the convergence of $$f_n = \sin \left(x+\frac{1}{n} \right)$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, uniform, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

It converges to $\sin x$ and $$||\sin (x+\frac{1}{n}) - \sin x ||_{\infty} \leq ||x + \frac{1}{n} - x||_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, so the convergence is uniform.

Is this an okay argument?

Comment: Your argument would be OK if you proved first $$|\sin a -\sin b| \le |a-b|$$ (see Guy Fsone's answer). Otherwise, one could think that you lightheartedly computed the estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Argument is Okay as well

since

$$\sin a -\sin b  = 2\sin(\frac{a-b}{2})\cos(\frac{a+b}{2})$$
Together with $$|\sin x|\le |x|$$

One get

$$|\sin a -\sin b|  = |\sin(\frac{a-b}{2})\cos(\frac{a+b}{2})|\le |a-b|$$

Therefore

$$\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}\|\sin (x+\frac{1}{n}) - \sin x |\leq \sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|x + \frac{1}{n} - x|  =\frac1n\rightarrow 0$$

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this argument is okay, because the second displayed equation is hardly different from a restatement of what you are trying to prove.  Why is it true, or rather, what about the $\sin$ function makes it true?

A good answer would make this clear, and would also make it clear if the same argument would work for any continuous periodic function, and not just the $\sin$ function.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that it is unclear in that sense. However, I am checking to make sure the inequality $\sin x < x$ is valid with supremum norms

Comment: What you should say is something like: "$|\sin(x+a)-\sin(x)|\le a$ for all real $a$ and $x$, so ..." or "$\sin x$ is *uniformly continuous* on the reals, so..."